# Why did the Chinese government transferred responsibility for managing the border to the army from the police in 2003?

Tags: china

The Chinese government transferred responsibility for managing the border to the army from the police in 2003.[17] Chinese authorities began building wire fences "on major defection routes along the Tumen River" in 2003.[18] Beginning in September 2006,[18] China erected a 20 kilometres (12 mi) fence on the border near Dandong, along stretches of the Yalu River delta with lower banks and narrower width.[1] The concrete and barbed wire fence ranged in height from 8 feet (2.4 m) to 15 feet (4.6 m).[18]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China%E2%80%93North_Korea_border

I am wondering if it making crossing more difficult or not. You would think it would make it more difficult, but I am not sure if it makes any sizeable difference when you do so. Anyway, the article mentions it, but doesn't mention why the government decided to do so and the rationale given for doing so.

Comment: If they don't say we cannot know for sure. It may simply be a practical reason, like the bureaucracy looked at bit better this way than the other.

Comment: Some ideas that come to my mind would be: a) manpower: soldiers are already hired and most of them do not have much to do during peacetime, so rotating them (specially if they are relatively untrained conscripts) would be more economical than using trained LEO. b) logistics: if the area is sparsely populated, the military could be more suited to setup a presence (create camps, aerial reconoissance, patrolling rough terrain).

Comment: Actually, CAPF Border Defence Force, which takes the responsibility of defending China's borders, was a part of PLA before March 2018. Only after March 2018 they are a part of police. So the "police" that you mentioned in the topic is actually a part of PLA in 2003.